# Laser light radiation interactions with biological tissues?

Tags: visible-light, laser, geometric-optics, biophysics

I was wondering what are the interaction between light generated by a laser source and biological tissues (e.g. human skin) in terms of geometric optics.
I suppose from my studies that a part of the radiation would be absorbed by the tissue causing for example thermal effects, but I'm interested to know more about the reflected, diffused and transmitted light.
Does anyone know more about this? Thank you very Much. L.